# How to make a checkbox rounded

Tags: xml, xaml, maui

I met some issues with radiobuttons in Maui:

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11418

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/7595

So I decided use a group of checkboxes instead, I need to make a checkbox look like radiobutton, I mean to make it round. I did not find any simple solution on the net.

Comment: Write your own control/handler/renderer. I think custom control with image + label is simple enough, and no platform specific code will be needed.

Comment: Just check https://github.com/FreakyAli/Maui.FreakyControls and if you find something missing raise a feature request :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use .NET MAUI handler to set the corner radius for CheckBox. Take a look at the following example:

1.Create a new control which subclass CheckBox:

```
public class MyRoundedCornerCheckBox : CheckBox
{
}
```

2.Consume it in xaml,

```
<local:MyRoundedCornerCheckBox />
```

3.And in code behind, you could use Handler to modify the checkbox,

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ModifyCheckBox();

    }

    public void ModifyCheckBox()
    {
        Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.CheckBoxHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("MyCustomization", (handler, view) =>
        {
            if (view is MyRoundedCornerCheckBox)
            {

#if WINDOWS
                handler.PlatformView.CornerRadius = new Microsoft.UI.Xaml.CornerRadius(20);
#endif
            }          
        });
    }
```

For more info, you could refer to [Customize controls with handlers.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize)

Hope it helps!